# Using Today() and Mid in excel

Tags: excel

Excel cell should have the below value
 ABC,04-04-2014

the date entered shouldn't be hard coded.
I need it by using
Today() or some other function.

Comment: Please can you re-word the question. I'm not clear on exactly what you are asking for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

```
="ABC," & TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

or

```
="ABC," & TEXT(TODAY(),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

depending on your desired date format.

Comment: +1 but note that TODAY() is a **volatile** function.

Comment: @Bathsheba I concur but it is what the Poster wanted

Comment: I'm sorry, can someone please explain how is it volatile?